# Is there a way to debug cscope?

Tags: command-line, tools

I'm trying to build a cscope code database (running `cscope -Rb`) on a reasonably-sized (not huge) codebase.

However, cscope is not returning, after over an hour. Over the past few months that I've been using it, cscope has completed creating the database (with previous iterations of the same codebase) in *maybe* as long as a minute. `htop` reports that cscope is using 100% of one CPU.

I assume there's a bad code file somewhere that is causing the problem, but how do I determine which one it is, if cscope just puts itself into what seems to be an infinite loop?

Comment: You may try with `lsof | grep cscope `